# Direct sum of simple modules and Schur's Lemma

Tags: proof-verification, modules, abstract-algebra, direct-sum

> Suppose $M,N$ are two non-isomorphic simple $R$-modules. For $m,n\geq1$, is it true that
>   $$
> \text{Hom}_R(M^{\oplus m},N^{\oplus n})\cong\hat{0}\,?
> $$

I think it's true by Schur's Lemma.

However, I don't think $M^{\oplus m}$ will be simple in general, e.g. take $M:=R:=\mathbb{R}$ and $m:=2$, then I think $\mathbb{R}\oplus\hat{0}$ is a non-trivial left ideal of $M^{\oplus m}$, so it is a non-trivial submodule of $M^{\oplus m}$.

I think the reason is that
$$
\text{Hom}_R(M^{\oplus m},N^{\oplus n})\cong[\text{Hom}_R(M,N)]^{\oplus mn},
$$
where Schur's Lemma applies to each term in the direct sum of the RHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isomorphism of Hom group is already very good, but if you want to you can attack it this way:

If $f:M^m\to N^n$ was a nonzero homomorphism, then $f$ must be nonzero on one of the copies of $M$, and the restriction to this copy creates an injection of $M$ into $N^n$. I'll recycle the letter and call the image of this injection $M$ again.

Since $N^n$ is semisimple, $M\oplus K=N^n$ for some submodule $K$ of $N^n$. We can refine this decomposition by decomposing $K$ into simple submodules. By the [Krull-Schmidt theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%E2%80%93Schmidt_theorem), this refinement and $N^n$ are equivalent, so that they have the same number of terms and after some permutation, the components are isomorphic. But this would mean $M$ is isomorphic to one of the copies of $N$ in the decomposition $N^n$.

This proves the contrapositive of the desired statement.